# .groupby() the Gender column and find the mean Wage of each group in Pandas

Tags: group-by

i cant find the best way to solve it.
here is my code snippet code
wage_means = tidy_wages.groupby('Gender')['Wage'].mean()
wage_means

Thank you guys!

.groupby() the Gender column and find the mean Wage of each group in Pandas

how can i write the code in each mean Wage of each group ?